# complexity of comparing two strings

Tags: php, complexity-theory

```
$haystack = array('T', 'h', 'i', 's', 'i', 's', 's', 'r', 'i', 'k', 'a', 'n', 't', 'h');
$needle = array('s', 'r', 'i', 'k', 'a', 'n', 't', 'h');
$array = array();
$k = -1;

$m = count($needle);
$n = count($haystack);
//****************1st type********************
for ($i = 0; $i < $m; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < $n; $j++) {
        if ($needle[$i] == $haystack[$j]) {
            $array[++$k] = $needle[$i];
            //echo $needle[$i]."<br/>";
            break;
        }
    }
}
//********************2nd type**************************
$found_array = array();
$j = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    if ($needle[$j] == $haystack[$i]) {
        $found_array[] = $needle[$j];
        $j++;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($found_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

As you could see I am comparing 2 strings...using 2 different types.
what is complexity of each of them?
My answer is O(NM) for both..Am I correct???

Comment: Please don't tag [c#] and [java] if there is no C# or Java code.

Comment: and why are you doing this in php?

Comment: All these edits make me wish SO had a CMM editing system too.

Comment: @BoltClock: I looked up "Capability Maturity Model", but Wikipedia didn't explain it well...

Comment: @Jonah: I meant copy-modify-merge, sorry :P

Comment: I am fluent in PHP only....I thought this question is not pertinent to programming language...so any one can answer this...and I used arrays because I felt that would be simple

Comment: @BoltClock: ah.  "Capability Maturity Model" was the first result for "CMM" :D .  I don't know why my formatting changes keep getting rolled back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the top one is O(NM) because you have the two nested for loops.

The bottom one is O(N) as you only traverse the needle array.

Comment: In the second case I am traversing through haystack(n times)..and comparing needle(m times)...

Comment: actually, you aren't. you are comparing N times. You only have one for loop and the comparison is O(1) complexity. Unless your code is wrong, that's what the complexity is.